# Unable to get the reference to spinner in the onCreate statement

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
        xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

       <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout file and also imports

Comment: What specific error are you getting? Can you show us your XML layout?

Comment: Can you post the activity_homepage.xml as well?  Without seeing that, it's hard to tell why that would fail.  Did you include a Spinner control with the android:id="@+id/spinner1"?

Comment: here is the XML part
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Imports Part

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.*;

Comment: I have already referred to the developer.android way of implementing the spinner it do not solves the problem. Working on version 4.0.3API

Comment: What specific error are you seeing?

Comment: Error : "spinner1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: @frenziedherring can you send me a spinner application built on 4.0.3? I mean a zip file. If yes Mail me please!! Stuck from hours.

Comment: Sounds like R by default imported from `android.R`. Try to write manually something like `import [yourpackage].R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have proper XML layout.  Try to clean your project (aka recreate `gen`).

Project-> Clean -> Ok.  After, refresh your project to recreate `R.java`. Might help you.

The other reason might wrong path for `R.java` file

Sometimes you don't see any import of `R` at all.

So add it manually: `import [yourpackage].R`

For example: `import com.demo.agnt.R`

or replace old one: for example `import android.R` to `import [yourpackage].R`

Comment: the problem exists still. Is it related to API 4.0.3 specifically??

Comment: @user1771128  I don't think so. Please , take a look on import R. from where do you import it? Not like: `import android.R;`